# req.body returnig always empty in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, http, middleware

```
const app = express();

app.use(express.json()); 
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true })); 

app.post("/", (req, res) => {
    res.status(200).json(req.body);
});
```

sending empty object always

I am using Thunder-client.
I am sending data through body form
but it's always returning empty object

[image: 1]

Comment: are you using body-parser? 
https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/body-parser.html

Comment: Can you show how you send the request body with a screenshot?

Comment: I had same problem. make sure you add ```Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded``` on your headers.

Comment: @AtinSingh  I am using latest expressjs.

Comment: @SuleymanSah just attached screenshot

Comment: @ImanHosseiniPour Its working, but object key is unusual. l am confused.

Comment: `const {random_data} = req.body` easy way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Content-type of `Form` is `multipart/form-data` and content-type of `Form-encode` is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. Does your data you want to post contain more than one type (like `image` along with `text/plain`)? If your data you want to post contains more than one type, look [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/data-chunks-in-node-js).
If it doesn't, add `Content-type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded` to the header and send post via `Form-encoded` option. Good Luck :)

```
const app = express();

app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.post("/", (req,res) => {
  res.status(200).json(req.body["random-data"]);
  // Result = lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
});
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for. My problem is resolved. Thanks...